# I want to add new property to object created from array

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am creating response from objects return from MySQL result

```
$q=mysql_query("SELECT userid,fullname FROM users");
while($r=mysql_fetch_objects($q)){
    $ar[]=$r;
}
echo json_encode($ar);
```

Here `$r` has two properties `userid` and `fullname`. 
Now I want to add a new property to `$r` object. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case $r should just be a standard object, so you can just do:

```
$r->somVarName = "some val";
```

Answer (score 1):

> Here $r have two property userid and fullname Now i want to do is add new property to $r 
>   object how can i do this?

Either select an extra field from the users table, if that data is actually in the database, or set it dynamically in PHP;

```
<?php
$q=mysql_query("SELECT userid, fullname, my_other_column FROM users");
while($r=mysql_fetch_object($q)){
    $r->newProperty = 'my content';
    $ar[]=$r;
}
echo json_encode($ar);
```

Comment: i did something like this but do you have any method other selecting other row

Comment: See the `$r->newProperty`. It's the same as the other answer, really.